# Is it possible to use a file in an installation folder during the install?

Tags: installation

I have an installer which runs a .exe which is going to try to access a file in the folder that the installer creates. Is it possible to do this? I am afraid I have to let the installer finish before being able to do that.

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2013 InstallShield limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was in the .exe. I had a line of code which read:

```
LPSTRS args = TEST("\C C:\\Program File\\.....");
```

The command line would try to run C:\Program.

Solution:

```
LPSTR args = TEST("\C \"C:\\Program File\\....\"");
```